# Turing machines which halt after updating a cell for the second or third time

Tags: turing-machines, computability

We say that a Turing machine is *fragile*, if it halts after changing the symbol of one of the tape cells for the third time. Is it true that every language that is solvable on a Turing machine will be solvable on a fragile Turing machine?

What can we say about Turing machines which stop after changing the symbol of one of the tape cells for the *second* time?

Comment: Try the following idea: simulate a Turing machine using a fragile Turing machine by copying the tape every single step.

Comment: *Thank you in advance for your solution.* This site is not for cheating.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247052/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143833/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

If the Turing machine is allowed to update each cell twice (or even once, see Hendrik Jan's comment), then you can use the following strategy to simulate an arbitrary Turing machine $T$ using a fragile Turing machine $T'$. For each step of $T$, the contents of the tape of $T$ will appear in some part of the tape of $T'$, with the head position highlighted. To simulate a step of $T$, the machine $T'$ copies the current contents of the tape of $T$ to the right of the current position, while modifying it in the process to implement the step of $T$. If implemented carefully, each cell is only updated twice.

Comment: I was wondering about this updating once. For copying we write in the new cell (first update) and we mark the old cells (as "done", second update at that position). But what if we leave blank space between the tape cells? Say we use one additional cell for each tape position. Then the TM can read two cells at once, but can mark the cells as "done" at the prosition next to the original contents. Would that work, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Right, this seems to work. Thanks for the correction. A fragile TM is essentially a 2DFA if it is not allowed to update the tape *at all*.